# why i can not find WebRootPath in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

this is my code

when i trying use it in method post it dont work and show me error
[image]

private readonly IWebHostEnvironment Environment;
public uploadController(IWebHostEnvironment _environment)
{
Environment = _environment;

```
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file!= null)
        {
            var uniqueFileName = GetUniqueFileName(file.FileName);

          
            var uploads = Path.Combine(Environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, uniqueFileName);
            file.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
        }    


            return Redirect("https://google.com");
    }
    private string GetUniqueFileName(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                  + "_"
                  + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4)
                  + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's your Uploads?

Comment: Do you have  wwwroot folder in your api project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Environment.WebRootPath can also be null if the wwwroot folder has been inadvertantly removed from the root of your project.

Try to add a wwwroot folder to the root of your project .

result:

[image]